# Why does the training accuracy of the model increase very slowly (almost stays stable) over some number of epochs?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am working on the CIFAR-10 dataset and trying to get the benchmark or atleast 90% accuracy. I have tried all the below mentioned ways but most of them result into the same thing and which is.... **the training accuracy doesn't improve after some epochs and stays stable and also the validation accuracy fluctuates a little bit.**

The dataset directory is as :

```
\cifar

   \train(total 40,000 images. 4000 images per class. Total 10 classes)   
      \airplane
      \automobile......(similar structure for test and validation as well)

   \test.(total 10,000 images. 1000 images per class)

   \validation.(total 10,000 images. 1000 images per class)

code.py
```

I have tried using the following parameters :

1. Optimizers : adam, nadam, adadelta and SGD.
2. Batch sizes : 16,32.
3. Initially started with 2 convolution layers. Firstly I trained with
   64 filters in both and then both convolution layers with 128
   filters. Now I have added a 3rd convolution layer.

Here is the code :

```
import keras

from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout, 
Activation, BatchNormalization, GlobalAveragePooling2D

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import optimizers, regularizers


classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), input_shape= (32,32,3), use_bias=False))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
classifier.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), use_bias=False))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
classifier.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), use_bias=False))
classifier.add(BatchNormalization())
classifier.add(Activation('relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
classifier.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())
classifier.add(Dense(units=10,activation='softmax'))

'''
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
'''

classifier.compile(optimizer='nadam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, 
   featurewise_center=True,featurewise_std_normalization=True, 
   shear_range=0.2,rotation_range=20, width_shift_range=0.2, 
   height_shift_range=0.2,horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, 
   featurewise_center=True,featurewise_std_normalization=True)

train_dataset=train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
   directory='cifar/train', target_size=(32,32), 
   batch_size=16, class_mode='categorical')

test_dataset=test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
   directory='cifar/validation', target_size=(32,32), 
   batch_size=16, class_mode='categorical')

classifier.fit_generator(train_dataset, 
   steps_per_epoch=2500, epochs=50, 
   validation_data=test_dataset, validation_steps=625)
```

And here are the epoch observations :

```
Epoch 17/50 
2500/2500 [==============================] - 259s 103ms/step - loss: 
0.9305 - acc: 0.6840 - val_loss: 0.8195 - val_acc: 0.7111

Epoch 18/50
2500/2500 [==============================] - 257s 103ms/step - loss: 
0.9280 - acc: 0.6817 - val_loss: 0.9981 - val_acc: 0.6816

Epoch 19/50
2500/2500 [==============================] - 260s 104ms/step - loss: 
0.9112 - acc: 0.6896 - val_loss: 0.9393 - val_acc: 0.6786

Epoch 20/50
2500/2500 [==============================] - 257s 103ms/step - loss: 
0.9053 - acc: 0.6881 - val_loss: 0.8509 - val_acc: 0.7172

Epoch 21/50
2500/2500 [==============================] - 259s 104ms/step - loss: 
0.9110 - acc: 0.6874 - val_loss: 0.8427 - val_acc: 0.7211

Epoch 22/50
2500/2500 [==============================] - 257s 103ms/step - loss: 
0.8967 - acc: 0.6944 - val_loss: 0.7139 - val_acc: 0.7592

Epoch 23/50
2500/2500 [==============================] - 257s 103ms/step - loss: 
0.8825 - acc: 0.6967 - val_loss: 0.8611 - val_acc: 0.7066

Epoch 24/50
2500/2500 [==============================] - 260s 104ms/step - loss: 
0.8819 - acc: 0.6967 - val_loss: 0.7436 - val_acc: 0.7447

Epoch 25/50
2500/2500 [==============================] - 270s 108ms/step - loss: 
0.8780 - acc: 0.6995 - val_loss: 0.8129 - val_acc: 0.7310

Epoch 26/50
2500/2500 [==============================] - 279s 112ms/step - loss: 
0.8756 - acc: 0.7010 - val_loss: 0.7890 - val_acc: 0.7276

Epoch 27/50
2500/2500 [==============================] - 283s 113ms/step - loss: 
0.8680 - acc: 0.7027 - val_loss: 0.8185 - val_acc: 0.7307

Epoch 28/50
2500/2500 [==============================] - 287s 115ms/step - loss: 
0.8651 - acc: 0.7043 - val_loss: 0.7457 - val_acc: 0.7460

Epoch 29/50
2500/2500 [==============================] - 286s 114ms/step - loss: 
0.8531 - acc: 0.7065 - val_loss: 1.1669 - val_acc: 0.6483

Epoch 30/50
2500/2500 [==============================] - 290s 116ms/step - loss: 
0.8521 - acc: 0.7085 - val_loss: 0.7221 - val_acc: 0.7565

Epoch 31/50
2500/2500 [==============================] - 289s 116ms/step - loss: 
0.8518 - acc: 0.7072 - val_loss: 0.7308 - val_acc: 0.7549

Epoch 32/50
2500/2500 [==============================] - 291s 116ms/step - loss: 
0.8465 - acc: 0.7119 - val_loss: 0.8550 - val_acc: 0.7182

Epoch 33/50
2500/2500 [==============================] - 302s 121ms/step - loss: 
0.8406 - acc: 0.7121 - val_loss: 1.0259 - val_acc: 0.6770

Epoch 34/50
2500/2500 [==============================] - 286s 115ms/step - loss: 
0.8424 - acc: 0.7120 - val_loss: 0.6924 - val_acc: 0.7646

Epoch 35/50
2500/2500 [==============================] - 273s 109ms/step - loss: 
0.8337 - acc: 0.7143 - val_loss: 0.8744 - val_acc: 0.7220

Epoch 36/50
2500/2500 [==============================] - 285s 114ms/step - loss: 
0.8332 - acc: 0.7144 - val_loss: 1.0132 - val_acc: 0.6753

Epoch 37/50
2500/2500 [==============================] - 275s 110ms/step - loss: 
0.8382 - acc: 0.7122 - val_loss: 0.7873 - val_acc: 0.7366
```

I am a beginner in deep learning so pardon me if I may have done any silly mistake. Please guide me how should I proceed further.

Comment: Your validation accuracy and loss is oscillating, it might be caused because of a high value of momentum in your optimizer. I suggest you also to try with a lower learning rate or increasing the decay.

Comment: Maybe it will be better to change the number of filters in convolution layers. Start with one layer of 64 filters and the other two with 128 filters. You can read this similar [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3366), it mught be helpfull

Comment: @Eric thank you for the suggestion. I will try that. Also, would the order of the convolution layers i.e. (filters) -- (128,128,64) or (128,64,128) or (64,128,128) affect the results significantly?

Comment: I think so, because every layer learns a specific property (contours, regions ...). But i just said it because the usual configuration is (64,128, 128), the best way to know it is to compare the results between this 3 coinfigurations.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try that as well @Eric.

Comment: That loss is pretty high for cross entropy, if you check most of your outputs are probably between 0.3 and 0.7, I suspect they're not confident predictions. I agree with the answer than your LR is high. Also you'll need to do dataset augmentation techniques. I suggest going through a tutorial like this on debugging neural networks: https://towardsdatascience.com/checklist-for-debugging-neural-networks-d8b2a9434f21

Answer (score 0):

Decrease your learning rate. Its too high